# \hyperlink{page.number} doesn't work all the time

Tags: page-numbering, hyperlink

`\hyperlink{page.#}` seems a little buggy. I tried it with roman page numbers. It worked with `ix` but not with `vii`.
Is there a way to refer to the physical page number , i.e. the one that shows in the counter at the top of the typeset PDF document?

I tried `truepage` but it did not work.

I tried negative numbers (e.g. `{page.-4}`). It did not work either...

Comment: Can you provide a minimal document with your setup that highlights the issue (see [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764))?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to absolute page numbers, but it's all or nothing.  Also, while [plainpages] will link to page ii as 2, it will not link to page 2 as 6.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\abspagenumber{\the\Hy@pagecounter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\hyperlink{page.2}{Go to page 2}

\hyperlink{page.6}{Go to page 6}

\lipsum[1-20]

\mainmatter

\abspagenumber

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

---

This gives you the option of linking to `\thepage` or `\theHpage` (absolute).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{Hpage}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\raisebox{\dimexpr \headheight+\headsep}[0pt][0pt]{\refstepcounter{Hpage}}}
\setcounter{Hpage}{1}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\hyperlink{page.2}{Go to page 2}

\hyperlink{page.ii}{Go to page ii}

\hyperlink{Hpage.2}{Go to Hpage 2}

\hyperlink{Hpage.6}{Go to Hpage 6}

\lipsum[1-20]

\mainmatter

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: the answer is a bit confusing, as you at first mention `plainpages` (which as you probably realized doesn't work here) and then set `hypertexnames`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I only mentioned plainpages to explain why I wasn't using it.